# confirming the creation of a file in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm a little new to this but I think I have successfully created a file for my android app to store some information using FileOutputStream. Before I get carried away and start doing useful things with it I would like to be able to see the contents of it and actually confirm that its there. Is there a way to do this with the emulator?

thanks for any advice in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, you can change to the DDMS perspective (usually, different code perspectives are found in the upper right corner of the GUI).  The DDMS perspective has a tab for file browsing attached devices (including both emulators and actual devices).

You can use this to look for both internal application files (available to your application only) and external storage files (those that reside on the sdcard, are available to other apps, and show up when mounted as USB on a computer).

There are buttons that allow you to push/pull files from the devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how to read a java File: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.io/how-to-read-file-in-java.html

And you can check if a file exists with http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists()

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way if your file is store as an application file is to copy it out to the SD card like this:

```
private void copy(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream( openFileInput(filename) );
    BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(
                    new File (
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            filename
                        )
                )
        );

    byte[] b = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    while ((read = bis.read(b)) != -1) { bos.write(b, 0, read); }

    bis.close();
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
}
```

Then you can use adb.exe to pull the file,

> adb.exe pull mnt/sdcard/yourfile saveasthis

If you want to use a GUI then open DDMS->File Explorer, go to mnt/sdcard and pull the file (push and pull are small icons with arrows to the right in the bar).